# Graceful shutdown of nodejs workers

Tags: node.js, worker

According to [nodejs docs](http://nodejs.cn/doc/node/child_process.html#child_process_child_disconnect) `child.disconnect()` shuts down the child process (worker) **gracefully**. Does that mean that all async callbacks, open db connections and currently active http requests are carefully considered by the worker before triggering `server.close()`?

If not, then what is the correct way to shutdown a web worker gracefully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok am going to try a detailed answer with links to various places for you to read and study.

First it is up to your code to create that graceful shutdown. If you code it yourself then `'SIGTERM'` needs to be coded properly. However, done correctly - Yes - it will close and wait for all requests and connection requests to finish while not accepting any new ones.

Here is a list:

1. [StackOverflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132154/debugging-a-graceful-shutdown-on-node-js)
2. [This if for a server outside documentation](http://www.codingdefined.com/2016/10/how-to-gracefully-shutdown-nodejs-server.html)
3. NPM library to do what you need - [async-exit-hook](https://www.pincer.io/npm/libraries/async-exit-hook)
4. [Shutdown NPM Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shutdown)
5. [Shutdown for Server NPM Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graceful-shutdown)
6. [Older outside documentation but still relevant](http://joseoncode.com/2014/07/21/graceful-shutdown-in-node-dot-js/)

Between studying the above and actually learning the libraries, you will find what you need.